# Site made with mod_wsgi-express takes too long to respond

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, iptables

I made a Web API using flask and I'm deploying it using mod_wsgi-express. I'm having a trouble where I can connect very easily to the website if I'm connected to the same server. However, when I try to connect to the website from outside. The site takes too long to respond and nothing is mentioned in the error log file or access log file

I installed mod_wsgi right onto python2.7.3

This is the command that I run from the terminal

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server configure.wsgi --server-root /home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/ --user www-data --group www-data --host serverIP --port 8000
```

Where Configure.wsgi is the setup application (I inserted it below for completeness)

```
from MenuUB2 import app as application

import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

The command line generates `mod_wsgi-start-server` generates the Httpd.conf file

I inserted the file below to make it easier for you guys

```
<IfModule !version_module>
LoadModule version_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_version.so'
</IfModule>

ServerName 161.116.80.72
ServerRoot '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/'
PidFile '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/httpd.pid'

ServerTokens ProductOnly
ServerSignature Off

User ${MOD_WSGI_USER}
Group ${MOD_WSGI_GROUP}

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_LISTENER_HOST>
Listen 161.116.80.72:8000
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_WITH_LISTENER_HOST>
Listen 8000
</IfDefine>


LockFile '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log//accept.lock'


<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_COMPRESS_RESPONSES>
<IfModule !deflate_module>
LoadModule deflate_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_deflate.so'
</IfModule>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_AUTH_USER>
<IfModule !auth_basic_module>
LoadModule auth_basic_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_auth_basic.so'
</IfModule>
<IfModule !auth_digest_module>
LoadModule auth_digest_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_auth_digest.so'
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_user_module>
LoadModule authz_user_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_authz_user.so'
</IfModule>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_PROXY>
<IfModule !proxy_module>
LoadModule proxy_module ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_proxy.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule !proxy_http_module>
LoadModule proxy_http_module ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_proxy_http.so
</IfModule>
</IfDefine>

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_PHP5>
<IfModule !php5_module>
Loadmodule php5_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/libphp5.so'
</IfModule>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfDefine>
</IfModule>


<IfVersion < 2.4>
DefaultType text/plain
</IfVersion>

TypesConfig '/etc/mime.types'

HostnameLookups Off
MaxMemFree 64
Timeout 60
ListenBacklog 500


<IfVersion >= 2.2.15>
RequestReadTimeout header=15-30,MinRate=500 body=15,MinRate=500
</IfVersion>

LimitRequestBody 10485760

<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

WSGIPythonHome '/usr'

WSGIVerboseDebugging 'Off'

<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGISocketPrefix /home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log//wsgi
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_MULTIPROCESS>
WSGIDaemonProcess 161.116.80.72:8000 \
   display-name='(wsgi:161.116.80.72:8000:1027)' \
   home='/home/xarxes_ub/python_code' \
   processes=1 \
   threads=5 \
   maximum-requests=0 \
   python-path='' \
   python-eggs='/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/python-eggs' \
   lang='es_ES.UTF-8' \
   locale='es_ES.UTF-8' \
   listen-backlog=100 \
   queue-timeout=45 \
   socket-timeout=60 \
   connect-timeout=15 \
   request-timeout=60 \
   inactivity-timeout=0 \
   deadlock-timeout=60 \
   graceful-timeout=15 \
   eviction-timeout=0 \
   shutdown-timeout=5 \
   send-buffer-size=0 \
   receive-buffer-size=0 \
   header-buffer-size=0 \
   response-buffer-size=0 \
   server-metrics=Off
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_MULTIPROCESS>
WSGIDaemonProcess 161.116.80.72:8000 \
   display-name='(wsgi:161.116.80.72:8000:1027)' \
   home='/home/xarxes_ub/python_code' \
   threads=5 \
   maximum-requests=0 \
   python-path='' \
   python-eggs='/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/python-eggs' \
   lang='es_ES.UTF-8' \
   locale='es_ES.UTF-8' \
   listen-backlog=100 \
   queue-timeout=45 \
   socket-timeout=60 \
   connect-timeout=15 \
   request-timeout=60 \
   inactivity-timeout=0 \
   deadlock-timeout=60 \
   graceful-timeout=15 \
   eviction-timeout=0 \
   shutdown-timeout=5 \
   send-buffer-size=0 \
   receive-buffer-size=0 \
   response-buffer-size=0 \
   server-metrics=Off
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>

WSGICallableObject 'application'
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIMapHEADToGET Auto

<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
WSGIRestrictStdin Off
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_PYTHON_PATH>
WSGIPythonPath ''
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_METRICS>
ExtendedStatus On
</IfDefine>

WSGIServerMetrics Off

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_STATUS>
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_KEEP_ALIVE>
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 0
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_KEEP_ALIVE>
KeepAlive Off
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_COMPRESS_RESPONSES>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_ROTATE_LOGS>
ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs \
    /home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/error_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M"
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_ROTATE_LOGS>
ErrorLog "/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/error_log"
</IfDefine>
LogLevel warn

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_ACCESS_LOG>
<IfModule !log_config_module>
LoadModule log_config_module ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_log_config.so
</IfModule>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "undefined" custom
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_ROTATE_LOGS>
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs \
    /home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/access_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M" common
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_ROTATE_LOGS>
CustomLog "/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/access_log" common
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CHUNKED_REQUEST>
WSGIChunkedRequest On
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_PROXY_HEADERS>
WSGITrustedProxyHeaders 
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_TRUSTED_PROXIES>
WSGITrustedProxies 
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_HTTPS>
<IfModule !ssl_module>
LoadModule ssl_module ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>
</IfDefine>

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 20
StartServers 1
MaxClients 20
MinSpareServers 1
MaxSpareServers 2
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxClients 1
MinSpareServers 1
MaxSpareServers 1
</IfDefine>
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 2
ThreadLimit 10
StartServers 1
MaxClients 20
MinSpareThreads 10
MaxSpareThreads 10
ThreadsPerChild 10
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 1
ThreadLimit 1
StartServers 1 
MaxClients 1
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 1
ThreadsPerChild 1
</IfDefine>
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
ThreadStackSize 262144
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 2
ThreadLimit 10
StartServers 1
MaxClients 20
MinSpareThreads 10
MaxSpareThreads 10
ThreadsPerChild 10
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
ServerLimit 1
ThreadLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxClients 1
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 1
ThreadsPerChild 1
</IfDefine>
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
ThreadStackSize 262144
</IfModule>

<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_VIRTUAL_HOST>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
NameVirtualHost *:8000
</IfVersion>
<VirtualHost _default_:8000>
</VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VIRTUAL_HOST>

<IfVersion < 2.4>
NameVirtualHost *:8000
</IfVersion>
<VirtualHost _default_:8000>
<Location />
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_ALLOW_LOCALHOST>
Allow from localhost
</IfDefine>
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_HTTPS_ONLY>
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName None
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_ALIAS>
ServerAlias None
</IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_REDIRECT_WWW>
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName unspecified
Redirect permanent / http://None:8000/
</VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_HTTPS_ONLY>
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName None
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_ALIAS>
ServerAlias None
</IfDefine>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://None:None%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_REDIRECT_WWW>
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName unspecified
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://None:None%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>

</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VIRTUAL_HOST>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_HTTPS>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_LISTENER_HOST>
Listen 161.116.80.72:None
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_WITH_LISTENER_HOST>
Listen None
</IfDefine>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
NameVirtualHost *:None
</IfVersion>
<VirtualHost _default_:None>
<Location />
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_ALLOW_LOCALHOST>
Allow from localhost
</IfDefine>
</Location>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile None
SSLCertificateKeyFile None
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VERIFY_CLIENT>
SSLCACertificateFile None
SSLVerifyClient none
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN>
SSLCertificateChainFile None
</IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:None>
ServerName None
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_ALIAS>
ServerAlias None
</IfDefine>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile None
SSLCertificateKeyFile None
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VERIFY_CLIENT>
SSLCACertificateFile None
SSLVerifyClient none
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN>
SSLCertificateChainFile None
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_HTTPS_ONLY>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_HSTS_POLICY>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security None
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SSL_ENVIRONMENT>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_REDIRECT_WWW>
<VirtualHost *:None>
ServerName unspecified
Redirect permanent / https://None:None/
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile None
SSLCertificateKeyFile None
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VERIFY_CLIENT>
SSLCACertificateFile None
SSLVerifyClient none
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN>
SSLCertificateChainFile None
</IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>

</IfDefine>

DocumentRoot '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/htdocs'

<Directory '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/'>
<Files handler.wsgi>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/htdocs/'>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_DIRECTORY_INDEX>
    DirectoryIndex None
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_DIRECTORY_LISTING>
    Options +Indexes
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CGI_SCRIPT>
    Options +ExecCGI
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_CGID_SCRIPT>
    Options +ExecCGI
</IfDefine>
    RewriteEngine On
    Include /home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log//rewrite.conf
<IfDefine !MOD_WSGI_STATIC_ONLY>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_DIRECTORY_INDEX>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_SERVER_STATUS>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/server-status
</IfDefine>
    RewriteRule .* - [H=wsgi-handler]
</IfDefine>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_ERROR_OVERRIDE>
WSGIErrorOverride On
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_HOST_ACCESS>
<Location />
    WSGIAccessScript 'None'
</Location>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_AUTH_USER>
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName '161.116.80.72:8000'
    AuthBasicProvider wsgi
    WSGIAuthUserScript 'None'
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_AUTH_GROUP>
    WSGIAuthGroupScript 'None'
</IfDefine>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    Require valid-user
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_AUTH_GROUP>
    Require wsgi-group 'wsgi'
</IfDefine>
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    <RequireAll>
    Require valid-user
<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_AUTH_GROUP>
    Require wsgi-group 'wsgi'
</IfDefine>
    </RequireAll>
</IfVersion>
</Location>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
WSGIHandlerScript wsgi-handler '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log//handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='161.116.80.72:8000' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
WSGIImportScript '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log//handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='161.116.80.72:8000' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
WSGIHandlerScript wsgi-handler '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log//handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='%{GLOBAL}' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
WSGIImportScript '/home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log//handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='%{GLOBAL}' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
</IfDefine>


<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_VERIFY_CLIENT>
<Location '/'>
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Location>
</IfDefine>
```

Here are my Apache details for those who want

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 17:25:42
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Is it possible that the server's firewall is blocking all external requests (external as in not connected to the same LAN) to the site
My server is running on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Either way I ran `sudo iptables -L` and got the following results

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8000 /* Allow HTTP */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I really appreciate any help that I can get

Comment: For a start, you should not really be passing the host IP to ``--host`` option. That is only for a fully qualified host name and only really when you need to do SSL, or restrict to a specific interface. Also don't do ``sys.stdout = sys.stderr`` as it is not needed. Finally ``--user www-data --group www-data`` is not needed if running as non privileged user as you likely would be since one running on port 8000.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I tried running following code from terminal

`mod_wsgi-express start-server configure.wsgi --server-root /home/xarxes_ub/python_code/Error_log/`

I still get the same problem

I even edited the configure.wsgi to become as following 
`from MenuUB2 import app as application

#import sys
#sys.stdout = sys.stderr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked port 8000 using a port knocking website such as this one
http://www.canyouseeme.org/

I found out that the port was closed. The only open port was port 80 and 22. The server I'm working on apparently has a firewall that I do not have access to.

As I result I had to change the httpd.conf file on port 80 and add the following lines

```
 WSGIScriptAlias /submitFrame /home/xarxes_ub/python_code/configure.wsgi
 WSGIDaemonProcess MenuUB2 threads=5 

<Directory /home/xarxes_ub/python_code>
            # WSGIScriptReloading On
        WSGIProcessGroup MenuUB2
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: You don't need ``WSGIScriptReloading On`` as that is the default. You don't need ``user=www-data group=www-data`` as that will also be the default.

Comment: Alright great
I'll change the answer with the new info